# How to create a new Highstock chart with new Highchart and not jquery?

Tags: highcharts

All the examples on the Highchart website creates a stockchart using:

`$('#container').highchart('Stockchart', config);`

How do I create a stock chart by simply using new? eg:

`var chart = new Highchart('Stockchart', config)`

I tried that, and this...

`var chart = new HighStock(config)`

...with no luck.

Answer (score 19):

I googled more and eventually found it.
To do it you code like this:

`chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(config)`

Annoying that they say that... anyway yeah, it has two constructors, Highcharts.Chart and Highcharts.StockChart.