# Highstock updating of the chart each second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

Im trying to get live data in highstock (js-lib). I used this template:
`http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update`
in combination with this guide: `http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data`

This is my result: `http://jsfiddle.net/93deqwm4/`
I dont get any new data every second. What is the problem, it looks so simple in the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go by parts, as Jack the Ripper said.

1. Your ajax call is using relative path, which means it's trying to reach 
   "http://fiddle.jshell.net/93deqwm4/show/live-server-data.php", that doesn't exist. You can change it to absolute path: "http://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server-data.php", but then the second problem appears:
2. You're trying to request a different domain than your page is on, so your browser is going to block it. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28848096/3494439) a very simple workaround if you use Chrome (if you don't, you can find other solutions there anyway).
3. You ignored the 2 step of the [tutorial you were following](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data). You must make the variable 'chart' global. So I used `window.chart` to make it global.

After these changes, you have a [functional example](http://jsfiddle.net/93deqwm4/1/) (<-- it won't work if you don't use a workaround to the 'different domain request' problem).

Comment: The example they have works grate. But I need to use "StockChart". They created a new chart by; `chart = new Highcharts.Chart` and then sending the data from requestData() to that chart. My problem is how do create a new chart (`chart = new Highcharts.Chart` but with StockChart. This doesent work: `chart = new $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {`

Comment: You can simply change `chart = new Highcharts.Chart` to  `chart = new Highcharts.StockChart`. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071593/how-to-create-a-new-highstock-chart-with-new-highchart-and-not-jquery